# Storing Qt application data files on Linux - not enough permissions

Tags: linux, qt, permissions

I have Qt application which should work on multiple platforms. One of those platforms is Linux. I am completely new in Linux world.

My application need to create and manage set of data files. After reading some links about linux directory structure I decided to store data files in /var/myapp directory and in its subdirectories.

Here is the problem: if my application runs without superuser privileges then it has no rights to create /var/myapp directory. Even if i will create directory manually (with sudo) my application will not have rights to write files there.

Is it possible to temporary elevate application's permissions from Qt code to create /var/myapp directory and write files there?

Or possibly there is another place in Linux directory structure which is by default available for storing application's data files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could distribute it without installation scripts, but you'd have to tell them to run it once as root... or have the app run itself as root using gksudo/kdesudo if its system wide data files do not exist.
The custom though is to make a package (.deb, .rpm, or even a .tar.gz that the user will extract himself) including all necessary files.
But linux (and OS X for that matter) are multi user systems. Are you sure your files belong in /var or /usr? If they're created at runtime as you say, don't they depend on user input? In which case you need to put them in some directory inside the user's home directory (getenv("HOME")).

Comment: I am not sure if my files belong to /var or /usr or ... But I am sure those files does not belong to single user. Those files belong to one or more external devices. My application communicates with external devices and stores results in directory tree which is hard specified by law of one specific country. So I search for appropriate place for this directory tree. Same Qt application compiled for Windows Mobile is distributed as simple executable which creates all needed directories on the fly when they are first used. It looks like such approach is impossible under Linux.

Comment: Oh, then you definitely want to try the sudo approach. Both kde and gnome have built in application (called gksudo/kdesudo) that will nicely ask the user for his password and then run as root <whatever you specify> - if said user is allowed to run stuff as root. So on startup you should check for your directories and if they're not there display an informative message and relaunch the app *just once* to recreate the files. It is bad form on Linux and OS X to require running as administrator, so please try to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Only root can create directories in /var. If your application needs a subdirectory under /var, you need to create it during installation (which typically runs with root permissions), and chmod it appropriately: either create a group for users that may run your application, put `/var/myapp` in that group, and chmod it to `770`; or just chmod the directory to `777` to allow everyone to access it. If you want to prevent writing by regular users, use 755 or 750 instead. (For data files, don't set the execute bit though: the appropriate permissions here are 666/660/644/640). Instead of octal triplets, you may prefer the more elaborate mnemoic syntax to chmod, e.g. `chmod ug+x filename` adds (`+`) the execute bit (`x`) to `filename` for the owning user (`u`) and group (`g`).

However, /var is not necessarily the best choice: /var is typically used for volatile data (temporary files etc.), as well as things that are expected to change frequently (mail, log files, etc.). Other data should go into either:

- `/usr/share/{appname}` for system-wide data files and resources
- `/etc/{appname}` for system-wide configuration files
- `~/.{appname}` (old convention) or `~/.config/{appname}` for per-user configuration files
- `/var/tmp/{appname}` for temporary files

Also, you want to make the `/usr` prefix configurable; most distributions reserve `/usr` for package-managed files, except `/usr/local`, which mirrors `/usr` for out-of-distro installs (so in that case, your system-wide resources go into `/usr/local/share` instead of `/usr/share`).

Comment: +1 Agreed, `/var` is *not* the right place for application data.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. So i can not distribute Linux application without installation scripts? I mean if my application need to store some system-wide data files then i need to use some additional scripts to create data directories (in /var/myapp or in /usr/local/share) and to change their permissions? So its impossible to simply send executable file to my clients?

Comment: You can run the executable just fine, you just can't touch the system-wide directories. If you want, you can make your application put everything in `~/.{myapp}`; and if you want to go beyond that, you should supply an installer and uninstaller script anyway. Installing things is what root is *for*, and it's a good thing that you can't easily get around this limitation.